# How to create a dynamic TabBarView/ Render a new Tab with a function in Flutter?

Tags: tabs, dart, widget, flutter, flutter-layout

So I have been learning flutter in a while and I am stuck in this. Sorry if it is a noobish question. I am currently trying to build something like a Card Tab. The information and widget will be stored in a card.

Imagine something like Tinder, where they have multiple card stack and swipe left and right to navigate.

I plan to create that but I cannot seems to find a way to add/render a new card with a button.

It's like adding something to the list, Flutter will use a ListView builder where we add to the list. But there is no TabBarView builder. Is this something that is not possible to do? I try putting a list inside a tab but it's still wont be the same.

I created some basic skeleton here to help convey my meaning. So the card will be swipe left and right and there is a button in the appBar to add card. Lenght is 2 now and I wanted the button to render the 3rd card. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new CardStack(),

  ));
}


class CardStack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => new _MainState();
}


class _MainState extends State<CardStack> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _cardController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cardController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cardController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: new AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              tooltip: 'Add Tabs',
              onPressed: null,
            ),
          ],
          title: new Text("Title Here"),
          bottom: new PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(20.0),
          child: new Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.grey),
            child: new Container(
              height: 50.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: new TabPageSelector(controller: _cardController),
            ),
          )
        )
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _cardController,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Center(
            child: new Card(
              child: new Container(
                  height: 450.0,
                  width: 300.0,
                  child: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 100.0),
                    tooltip: 'Favorited',
                    onPressed: null,
                  )
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Center(
            child: new Card(
              child: new Container(
                  height: 450.0,
                  width: 300.0,
                  child: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.local_pizza, size: 50.0,),
                    tooltip: 'Pizza',
                    onPressed: null,
                  )
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this.
[image: Demo]

To make dynamic tab you can use a List and keep appending the list on every button click.

Trick: Clear List and redraw an empty widget and again draw the widgets as per your list.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new CardStack(),
  ));
}

class DynamicTabContent {
  IconData icon;
  String tooTip;

  DynamicTabContent.name(this.icon, this.tooTip);
}

class CardStack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => new _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<CardStack> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<DynamicTabContent> myList = new List();

  TabController _cardController;

  TabPageSelector _tabPageSelector;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myList.add(new DynamicTabContent.name(Icons.favorite, "Favorited"));
    myList.add(new DynamicTabContent.name(Icons.local_pizza, "local pizza"));

    _cardController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myList.length);
    _tabPageSelector = new TabPageSelector(controller: _cardController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cardController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: new AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                tooltip: 'Add Tabs',
                onPressed: () {
                  List<DynamicTabContent> tempList = new List();

                  myList.forEach((dynamicContent) {
                    tempList.add(dynamicContent);
                  });

                  setState(() {
                    myList.clear();
                  });

                  if (tempList.length % 2 == 0) {
                    myList.add(new DynamicTabContent.name(Icons.shopping_cart, "shopping cart"));
                  } else {
                    myList.add(new DynamicTabContent.name(Icons.camera, "camera"));
                  }

                  tempList.forEach((dynamicContent) {
                    myList.add(dynamicContent);
                  });

                  setState(() {
                    _cardController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myList.length);
                    _tabPageSelector = new TabPageSelector(controller: _cardController);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
          title: new Text("Title Here"),
          bottom: new PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(10.0),
              child: new Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.grey),
                child: myList.isEmpty
                    ? new Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                      )
                    : new Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: _tabPageSelector,
                      ),
              ))),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _cardController,
        children: myList.isEmpty
            ? <Widget>[]
            : myList.map((dynamicContent) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new Container(
                      height: 450.0,
                      width: 300.0,
                      child: new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(dynamicContent.icon, size: 100.0),
                        tooltip: dynamicContent.tooTip,
                        onPressed: null,
                      )),
                );
              }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i ran this example..and i couldnt get the index of the current tab..as you are using a map to display all the tabs, i need the index to show certain components and hide some

Comment: There's an issue with this solution, where `TabPageSelector` loses it's state when a new `TabController` is instantiated inside `build()`. I'm also still trying to fix this issue. Please see: https://webmshare.com/ZQ00d

Answer (score 42):

Problems arise if you need to modify the arrays. They consist in the fact that when modifying an array you do not have the opportunity to use the same controller.

[image]

You can use the next custom widget for this case:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> data = ['Page 0', 'Page 1', 'Page 2'];
  int initPosition = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomTabView(
          initPosition: initPosition,
          itemCount: data.length,
          tabBuilder: (context, index) => Tab(text: data[index]),
          pageBuilder: (context, index) => Center(child: Text(data[index])),
          onPositionChange: (index) {
            print('current position: $index');
            initPosition = index;
          },
          onScroll: (position) => print('$position'),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            data.add('Page ${data.length}');
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTabView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTabView({
    super.key,
    required this.itemCount,
    required this.tabBuilder,
    required this.pageBuilder,
    this.stub,
    this.onPositionChange,
    this.onScroll,
    this.initPosition,
  });

  final int itemCount;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder tabBuilder;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder pageBuilder;
  final Widget? stub;
  final ValueChanged<int>? onPositionChange;
  final ValueChanged<double>? onScroll;
  final int? initPosition;

  @override
  CustomTabsState createState() => CustomTabsState();
}

class CustomTabsState extends State<CustomTabView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController controller;
  late int _currentCount;
  late int _currentPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentPosition = widget.initPosition ?? 0;
    controller = TabController(
      length: widget.itemCount,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: _currentPosition,
    );
    controller.addListener(onPositionChange);
    controller.animation!.addListener(onScroll);
    _currentCount = widget.itemCount;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CustomTabView oldWidget) {
    if (_currentCount != widget.itemCount) {
      controller.animation!.removeListener(onScroll);
      controller.removeListener(onPositionChange);
      controller.dispose();

      if (widget.initPosition != null) {
        _currentPosition = widget.initPosition!;
      }

      if (_currentPosition > widget.itemCount - 1) {
        _currentPosition = widget.itemCount - 1;
        _currentPosition = _currentPosition < 0 ? 0 : _currentPosition;
        if (widget.onPositionChange is ValueChanged<int>) {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            if (mounted && widget.onPositionChange != null) {
              widget.onPositionChange!(_currentPosition);
            }
          });
        }
      }

      _currentCount = widget.itemCount;
      setState(() {
        controller = TabController(
          length: widget.itemCount,
          vsync: this,
          initialIndex: _currentPosition,
        );
        controller.addListener(onPositionChange);
        controller.animation!.addListener(onScroll);
      });
    } else if (widget.initPosition != null) {
      controller.animateTo(widget.initPosition!);
    }

    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.animation!.removeListener(onScroll);
    controller.removeListener(onPositionChange);
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.itemCount < 1) return widget.stub ?? Container();

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            controller: controller,
            labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
            indicator: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            tabs: List.generate(
              widget.itemCount,
              (index) => widget.tabBuilder(context, index),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: controller,
            children: List.generate(
              widget.itemCount,
              (index) => widget.pageBuilder(context, index),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onPositionChange() {
    if (!controller.indexIsChanging) {
      _currentPosition = controller.index;
      if (widget.onPositionChange is ValueChanged<int>) {
        widget.onPositionChange!(_currentPosition);
      }
    }
  }

  void onScroll() {
    if (widget.onScroll is ValueChanged<double>) {
      widget.onScroll!(controller.animation!.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Yuriy Luchaninov, If I want to add the "delete page" option for tab view based on selection respective page should remove from the PageBuilder.

Comment: Please find the tab delete image link reference. https://ibb.co/9NPNkkZ