# Adding tab labels to TabView in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm trying to extend the TabView proposed as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036546/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tabbarview-render-a-new-tab-with-a-function-in-flutter).

Specifically, instead of the grey dots, I would like to have category labels, and load as a tab content a widget corresponding to that category.

I tried following the docs, but if I change something in the AppBar it just gives me a reendering error.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve what you wanted via `DefaultTabController` widget. You can see the example [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/tabs/) with only the icons. And here is the modified version of it with titles. `TabBar` part is for the tab and it's specifications. `TabBarView` is for the interior view.

```
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car), text: "Car",),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit), text: "Transit"),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike), text: "Bike",),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you use the code above, you would be getting a 3 tabbed tab view with the explanatory text.

**EDIT:**

```
//Call the widget as follows
new TabBarDemo(createTabsDynamically());

//method to use for dynamic creation.
List<Tab> createTabsDynamically() {

    List<String> titles = ["Car", "Transit", "Bike"];
    List<IconData> iconData = [Icons.directions_car, Icons.directions_transit, Icons.directions_bike];
    List<Tab> tabs = new List();
    // Assuming titles and icons have the same length
    for (int i = 0; i< titles.length; i++) {
      tabs.add(Tab(icon: Icon(iconData[i]), text: titles[i],));
    }

    return tabs;
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  List<Tab> tabs;
  TabBarDemo(this.tabs);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: tabs,
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can i do it dynamically? I have a variable Number of categories so for each category i Need a Tab.

Comment: First you can create your tabs according to your values, then you can pass it with constructor. I edited my code so you can have an idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you wanted via **TabController** widget. I found a simple example of TabBar [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/06/flutter-tab-bar-controller-and-left.html).