# how to populate flutter tabBar using an api response

Tags: api, flutter, backend, flutter-layout, tabbar

how can i populate TabBar in flutter using api response (array of strings), instead of hard-coded text like this..

```
TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: 'text1',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'text2',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'text3',
              ),

            ],
```

Comment: Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036546/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tabbarview-render-a-new-tab-with-a-function-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code for dynamic TabBar

```
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: List<Widget>.generate(
    apiResponse.length,
    (int index) {
      return Container(
        child: new Tab(
          child: Text("Api Response $index"),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: thank you so much i'll try your solution, but how can i append static tab to the dynamic tab list?

Comment: Create a list like this List<String> apiResponse = new List<String>(); and assign a response to that list. For example,  apiResponse = getData["results"][index]["text"];.