# How to wrote the condition for only ten dynamic tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I create some tab functions dynamically. I need only 10 tabs in that dynamic function can you respond to the condition for this method.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverFlow, post your code (Minimal, Complete, Reproducible) to get more targetted answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamic list of Tabs

Here is a small example app displaying a random dynamic list of Sports.

[image]

### Domain Layer

Each `TabItem` is defined with a `name` and a `description`.

```dart
part '66457422.dynamic_tabs.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class TabItem implements _$TabItem {
  const factory TabItem({
    String name,
    String description,
  }) = _TabItem;
  const TabItem._();

  String get initials =>
      name.split(RegExp(r'\W+')).map((x) => x[0].toUpperCase()).join('');

  static TabItem get random {
    final faker = Faker();
    return TabItem(
      name: faker.sport.name(),
      description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    );
  }
}
```

I used the [`freezed`](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package that provides immutability for my `TabItem`. `freezed` uses the [`build_runner`](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) package to generate the class implementation inside `66457422.dynamic_tabs.freezed.dart`.

In my `TabItem`, I defined to getters:

1. `String get initials` to get the initials of each Sport to be used as the Tabs labels.
2. `static TabItem get random` to generate a random Sport thanks to the [`faker`](https://pub.dev/packages/faker) package.

### State Management

To maintain the list of `TabItems`, you will need some kind of State Management. In this example, I use the [`riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) package (in its [`flutter_hooks`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) flavor) from the same author as `Provider`. But, you may use other State Management systems if you prefer. Check this [curated list](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

My `tabsProvider` is a `StateNotifierProvider` defined as follows:

```dart
final tabsProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TabsNotifier>(
    (ref) => TabsNotifier()..addTab()..addTab()..addTab());

class TabsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<TabItem>> {
  TabsNotifier([List<TabItem> state]) : super(state ?? []);

  void addTab() {
    state = [
      ...state,
      TabItem.random,
    ];
  }
}
```

### Presentation Layer

Now, we just need to display everything!

I used the `DefaultTabController` Widget and maps on the `List<TabItem>` provided by my `tabsProvider` to display the `Tabs` and the `TabViews`:

```dart
class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabs = useProvider(tabsProvider.state);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dynamic Tabs Demo'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: tabs.map((t) => Tab(text: t.initials)).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: tabs.map((t) => TabItemWidget(tabItem: t)).toList(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: tabs.length >= 10
            ? null
            : FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => context.read(tabsProvider).addTab(),
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `FloatingActionButton` will `addTab()` on my `tabsProvider` only if the number of `TabItems` is smaller than 10. Otherwise, it disappears.

Voilà! That's about it.

---

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```dart
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

part '66457422.dynamic_tabs.freezed.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Dynamic Tabs Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabs = useProvider(tabsProvider.state);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dynamic Tabs Demo'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: tabs.map((t) => Tab(text: t.initials)).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: tabs.map((t) => TabItemWidget(tabItem: t)).toList(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: tabs.length >= 10
            ? null
            : FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => context.read(tabsProvider).addTab(),
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TabItem tabItem;

  const TabItemWidget({Key key, this.tabItem}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(tabItem.name),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text(tabItem.description),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

final tabsProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TabsNotifier>(
    (ref) => TabsNotifier()..addTab()..addTab()..addTab());

class TabsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<TabItem>> {
  TabsNotifier([List<TabItem> state]) : super(state ?? []);

  void addTab() {
    state = [
      ...state,
      TabItem.random,
    ];
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class TabItem implements _$TabItem {
  const factory TabItem({
    String name,
    String description,
  }) = _TabItem;
  const TabItem._();

  String get initials =>
      name.split(RegExp(r'\W+')).map((x) => x[0].toUpperCase()).join('');

  static TabItem get random {
    final faker = Faker();
    return TabItem(
      name: faker.sport.name(),
      description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have default three tabs... In this first tab, I have one floating button when I click the floating then only create one by one ten dynamic tabs only ten tabs.

Comment: Okay, I think I better understand your question. Check my updated answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036546/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tabbarview-render-a-new-tab-with-a-function-in-flutter